# MySQL driver not found with Play 2.0

Tags: mysql, playframework-2.0, scalaquery

I'm trying to use ScalaQuery with play 2 but I keep getting a ""no suitable driver for ...' error. The database connection works fine with Anorm/Nina.
Here's my ScalaQuery code :

```
object Client extends Table[(Int, String)]("Client") {
val database = Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost/play2test", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" , user="root", password="root")

  def id = column[Int]("id", O NotNull, O AutoInc)

  def name = column[String]("name", O NotNull)

  def * = id ~ name
  def findAll = database.withSession {
    implicit db: Session =>
      (for (t <- this) yield t.id ~ t.name).list
  }
}
```

I added the sbt dependency:

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.21"
```

And I have this on application.conf

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1/play2test"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=root
```

(I tried to use the forDataSource method along with play's DB.getDataSource() but I didn't get any better results)

One awkward thing is that I cannot import com.mysql._, so apparently the driver wasn't even downloaded (despite sbt saying that it did). I tried even to download the jar and add it manually to a /lib folder under my project but the import still not working.

I'm stuck and I need a little help please. :(

EDIT: 
I deleted the "jdbc:mysql://localhost/play2test" and rewrited it (found that tip on another thread) and now I'm having a new problem :

```
[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '."id","t1"."name" FROM "Client" "t1"' at line 1]
```

Why is ScalaQuery using double-quotes for MySQL and how to change that ?

Edit2 : 
Problem solved, I had the wrong import for ScalaQuery's SQL driver.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem, however please add an answer and mark it as correct one when it will be possible (in next 2 days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy/pasted an O2 based code and forgot to change the SQLDriver import:

```
import org.scalaquery.ql.extended.MySQLDriver.Implicit._
```